# Modify joomla "submit article" page code-behind

Tags: html, css, joomla

On my Joomla site I have added a template, but it has messed up the "submit an article" page, by setting the fields in the publishing tab to `width: 0px;`. The html for the  category dropdown looks like:

```
<div id="jform_catid_chzn" class="chzn-container chzn-container-single" style="width: 0px;"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="chzn-single" tabindex="-1"><span>- Timesedler</span><div><b></b></div></a><div class="chzn-drop" style="display: none; width: 0px;"
```

This is pretty easy to fix by simply removing the `width: 0px;` but my problem is that I can't locate the file I need to alter, to make changes to the submit article page.

How do I locate the file?

**EDIT**

The CSS is working perfectly fine, but the style-tag in the HTML is the one i need to remove. So to sum up: I need to locate the file that makes up the HTML-code in the "Submit an Article" page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right-click (or ctrl-click on a mac) and use the Inspect element functionality in your web browser to see what css affects an element in your code, and in which file it is located. If you are using internet explorer (god forbid) there are some developer tools available in the menus.

Comment: `If you are using internet explorer (god forbid)` +1

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, as you can see in my html-code it both gets affected by the css file and the 'style="width: 0px;"'tag in the html-code.. If i inspect and remove the 'style="width: 0px;"' from within my browser, the fields get presentet correct.

So what i need to locate is the html file, that is making up the "Submit new article" page.

Comment: you can override the style in the html by using width: auto !important; Or else you need to locate the php-file that generates the output. I guess this is the /components/com_content/views/form/tmpl/edit.php, or in an overridden version of this file in your template: /templates/yourtemplate/html/com_content/form/edit.php

Comment: I tried the override method as you suggested.. it worked for some of the elements, but alot of other elements on the site went crazy. I will try to locate the php file :)

Comment: You need to make sure you only apply the css to the element that you want to change. #jform_catid_chzn {width: auto !important;} should theoretically do the trick; id's should be unique on the page, but often they are not. Alternatively you could try  #jform_catid_chzn[style="width: 0px;"], which should at least only apply to elements with this particular id, and which has a style element with width=0 ...

Comment: I solved it with the "width: auto !important" , thanks for the answer.